# Display related content only if one particular option is selected from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Right now if I select any of the options in the list it will display an input field but I would like to change it in a way that it shows the input filed only if "Other" is selected.

How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.actions_new_location = ["Studio", "Conservation Studio", "Gallery", "Other"];
    self.actions_new_location_selected = ko.observable();
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<li class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>Location of Photography</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <select data-bind="options: actions_new_location, value: actions_new_location_selected, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
  </div>
</li>
<!-- to be shown only if "Other" is selected -->
<li class="row" data-bind="visible: actions_new_location_selected">
  <div class="col-3 col-offset-3">
    <label>Please describe
      <input type="text" data-bind="" />
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the check in your binding's visibility check:

```
<li class="row" data-bind="visible: actions_new_location_selected() === 'Other'">
  <div class="col-3 col-offset-3">
    <label>Please describe
      <input type="text" data-bind="" />
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Huh, that was easy! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Make it a computed observable, this will be more unit testable and reusable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.actions_new_location = ["Studio", "Conservation Studio", "Gallery", "Other"];
    self.actions_new_location_selected = ko.observable();
    self.actions_other_selected = ko.computed(function() {
       return self.actions_new_location_selected() === "Other";
    });
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<li class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>Location of Photography</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <select data-bind="options: actions_new_location, value: actions_new_location_selected, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
  </div>
</li>
<!-- to be shown only if "Other" is selected -->
<li class="row" data-bind="visible: actions_other_selected">
  <div class="col-3 col-offset-3">
    <label>Please describe
      <input type="text" data-bind="" />
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: `actions_new_location_selected` is the variable that holds the selection, you'd have to add a new computed that checks it